# Do I use Filebeat, Ingest or Pipelines to get rid of Logstash in my ELK stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I'm fairly new to filebeat, ingest, pipelines in ElasticSearch and not sure how they relate.

In my old environments we had ELK with some custom grok patterns in a directory on the logstash-shipper to parse java stacktraces properly. The logstash indexer would later put the logs in ES.

How do I do this without Logstash? And how do I parse custom log formats?

Comment: You need to configure logstash. This consists basically in three steps. 1)  input plugin setup: choose one that's suitable with your log shipping method (such as filebeat). 2) After that you'll need to enrich/parse your log entries (and you can still use grok to parse them if you need it). 3) Finally you're gonna want to write this logs somewhere (elasticsearch I guess) using an output plug-in.